# Using Laplace transforms find the solution to a differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

> $$ y'+\frac{2}{t}y= t - 1 + \frac{1}{t}. $$

with initial condition $y(1)=1/2$

I know how to do it using Laplace transformations when initial condition is of $y(0)=a$ where $a$ is a constant but not otherwise because we were taught the Laplace transform of $y'$ is $sY(s)-y(0).$

I can solve this equation easily with a linear approach.

solution being

$$y(t)=(t^2/4)-(t/3)+(1/2)+(1/(12t^2))$$

> Can someone show me how to solve this initial value problem using Laplace transforms? I'm stuck.

Comment: Considering the function $w(t) = y(t+1)$ might help. You would have to shift the $t$'s in your equation too though. On the other hand, you will have $w(0) = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Are you asked to use Laplace transform technique to solve it?

Comment: What you're saying is replace all my t's with (t+1) and then solve as though my initial condition was y(0)=1/2?

Comment: No, but I was wondering if you could. This way on my final I wouldn't have to know all the different specific methods for solving IVP's. All I would need to really know inside out is Laplace.

Comment: Usually, we use Laplace transform to solve differential equations with constant coefficients

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Since you know how to solve it using LT (I do not think it is possible to do so, but solving it using an Integrating Factor or as an Exact Equation is doable), proceed and solve it that way while maintaining a constant for $y(0) = c$ in all the calculations.

Once you have the solution for $y(t)$, substitute $y(1) = \dfrac{1}{2}$ to solve for $c$.

The solution should be:

$$y(t) = \dfrac{1}{12}\left(3 t^2 + \dfrac{1}{t^2} - 4t + 6\right)$$

Comment: Nice my dear friend. :)